# How to get Java's-Card-Layout kind of effect in CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, swing, css

**EDIT:-**

[image]

In a nutshell, the question is: **How are different div's going to display on the same place on the click of a button?**

---

I have some experience of development in Java Programming Language. There I used the Swing framework to develop the GUI's.

Now I am in some need to develop a *user interface* of a *web page*. I am told that the user interface is of a *PHP application*, and I will most probably use *HTML, CSS, Javascript etc*. for it.

Now in *Java Swing*, we had *layout managers* like ***Grid Layout, FlowLayout, CardLayout***.

I want to ask that:

1. Is there *something like layout managers* in web design? Are they a
   part of **CSS**? If yes, **what are they calle**d? **What should I search to
   learn about them?**
2. I need a part of the page to have it's contents
       like in a card layout (in Java) --- *that is if it was Java Swing
       based UI, I would simply use a card layout manager, then add a few
       panels to it, and the next panel would display on a click of a
       button.*
       **I want the same kind of functionality in a web page? How can I
   achieve it through CSS?**

Comment: AFAIK all layout is managed by css and browser default styles, maybe you should look a CSS framework like foundation, bootstrap or skeleton, their bring some layout and responsive functionality

Comment: To create a layout, you make a `<div>` in HTML and then put other `<div>`s inside of it. *Then* you assign width, height, float, etc. properties in CSS. Your question as it stands is both too broad and too unclear for us to help you.

Comment: Look up 'Bootstrap'. If you haven't already heard of it, it's a responsive framework. Within the framework, you can then start to build your website. As for the UI being of a 'PHP application', you probably want to look up 'CMS'. There are various CMS's about, they are primarily built using a PHP framework.

Comment: @Blazemonger The three right panels display on the click of a button associated with them. All three right-panels share the same display area/space on the page. I need this kind of thing.

That is, let's say three div's, sharing the same place on the page such that, one the click of a button the first div is displayed, then on the click of a button, the second div is displayed on the same place, and then on the click of a button, the third div is displayed. That's essentially what I need.

Comment: @Zarah each separate 'panel' in your case would be a separate div. Think of divs as containers which contain whatever you put in them. How the content displays within the div is up to you depending on how you want to style it using CSS. Going by what you've asked and said, I suggest looking up the basics of HTML first and going through things step by step instead of jumping straight into frameworks and getting confused with what stuff means.

Comment: @Blazemonger Am posting a pictore in the question (not exactly what I want to make but it does give an exact idea. There are four buttons on the left and then there is content (a panel of text and a picture) on the right. Let's call the right side 'textarea PLUS picture' our right panel. Now there are three different right panels. The first right-panel displays on the click of first button (the Testimonials button), the second right-panel displays on the click of the second button (the Special Awards button) and the third right-panel displays on the click of third button (Recognition button).

Comment: @AndrewMatthew Thank you very much for the suggestion. I am just going to do that. I just wanted an overview of how to display different content at the same place on the click of a button. That is this part of the page is dynamic.